# jQuery adding and removing classes dynamically when the user clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I've a problem with the following code. I've two tabs in my navigation **Tab-1 & Tab-2**, when the user click on any tab, then I want to add the **active** class to it and at the same time I want to remove the active class from previously active tab. Also the tab which is currently active should display its content and have to hide the remaining content. It means when the user clicked on any tab it should display only its content and the other contents should be hidden. Please help me thank you.

```
<style>
    .wrapper .tabs {
        display: none;
    }
    .wrapper .tabs.active {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1">Tab-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab-2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Panel-1 -->
    <div id="tab-1" class="tabs active">
        <p>Tab-1 Content</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Panel-2 -->
    <div id="tab-2" class="tabs">
        <p>Tab-2 Content</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
<!-- Script -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.nav li').click(function() {
            $('.nav li.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });

        // To display content for active class only
        $('.nav li').click(function() {
            $('.wrapper .tabs.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.eq()`, `.index()` at `click` event attached to selector `"a[href^='#tab-']"` which selects element where `href` begins with `#tab-`, create variable referencing elements where `id` begins with `tab-`, call `event.preventDefault()` within `click` function to prevent navigation to document fragment, `.hide()`, `.show()`

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
     var a = $("a[href^='#tab-']");
     var tabs = $("[id^=tab]");
     a.click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       tabs.hide().eq(a.index(this)).show()
     })
   })
```

```css
#tab-1 {
  display: block;
}
[id^="tab"]:not(#tab-1) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js">
</script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#tab-1">Tab-1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#tab-2">Tab-2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Panel-1 -->
  <div id="tab-1" class="tabs active">
    <p>Tab-1 Content</p>
  </div>
  <!-- Panel-2 -->
  <div id="tab-2" class="tabs">
    <p>Tab-2 Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've one more doubt, what if I've different href values instead of tab-1, tab-2, something like home, gallery..

Comment: @e-Designary _"what if I've different href values instead of tab-1, tab-2, something like home, gallery"_ Does not appear at original Question?

Comment: It is not provided in the original question, but my doubt is if I've the nav like this, will it work?
<ul class="nav"> 
     <li> <a href="#home">Home</a> </li> 
     <li> <a href="#gallery">Gallery</a> </li> 
</ul>

Comment: @e-Designary _"It is not provided in the original question"_ How can an Answer be provided if description of details is not included at Question? _"but if I've the nav like this <ul class="nav"> <li> <a href="#tab-1">Tab-1</a> </li> <li> <a href="#tab-2">Tab-2</a> </li> </ul>"_ That is same `html` as is at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 Like this, <ul class="nav"> <li> <a href="#home">Home</a> </li> <li> <a href="#gallery">Gallery</a> </li> </ul>

Comment: You can use selector `.nav a`; e.g., `var a = $(".nav a")` returns same result and omits using attribute selector